# Why does invalid handle exception occur when browsing via WPF WebBrowser control?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a WPF app that has a window with a WebBrowser control in  it.  I navigate to a site like http://www.cnn.com, it loads, and then I get an error when I click a link.  This only happens when debugging on a Windows Server VM that has VS 2010 on it.  Running the compiled app out of the bin or debugging on my Win7 machine works fine.

With unmanaged debugging off you just get the vshost32.exe has stopped working.  The specific error seen if I enable unmanaged debugger is an "invalid handle exception".

Any thoughts on what to look for between the two environments or why this would happen?